# Laravel : gates and policies vs normal function

Tags: laravel

I did that to test if an user can access to a resource:

1. I created a function in a "global" service:

   ```
    class IsAuthorizedToRessource{

        public function isAuthorizedToUser($connectedUserId, $userId){
            // return true or false
        }
    }
   ```
2. In my controller I call this service:

   ```
    protected $isAuthorizedToRessource;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isAuthorizedToRessource = new IsAuthorizedToRessource();
    }

    public function show(Request $request,$id)
    {

        if (! $this->isAuthorizedToRessource->isAuthorizedToUser(Auth::user()->id, $id)){
            return response()->json("not authorized to this ressource", 403);
        }

        //....
    }
   ```

All is running fine. But I saw in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization) that there is the "gates" and "policies". Despite of the documentation, I don't understand these concepts. And I have tried a lot of things without success.

My question: is my current technique sustainable? or should I make the effort to use these techniques "gates" and "policies"?

How can I use these techniques? (I specify: I do not use a model - I saw there is a "with" and a "without" model technique).

Comment: why don't you use spatie/laravel-permission: https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: Hi Sonat, this library "laravel-permission" is to manage roles and tasks. My question is "how to protect a ressource", and not to check if a user can do a task. But Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Laravel gates or policies are foR granular level permission.  See [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gates-and-policies-in-laravel--cms-29780) article which can help you understand it even more. Once you get hold of it, it's extremely powerful.

Comment: Thanks Mihir for the link. I understood and I managed to make this system work. By cons I am not completely convinced by this solution. My initial solution works very well too. But thanks again. DOm